# run openvpn and openconnect simultaneously on windows 10

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vpnc

I want to establish 2 vpn connections by using openvpn and openconnect on Windows 10. The openvpn connection is used to keep a tunnel with my remote PC through my VPS（Virtual private server） which acts as a virtual switch. The openconnect connection is used to circumvent all my internet traffic. Everything is ok when they are used separately. But when I first run the openvpn to establish a tunnel successfully, then run the openconnect. the openconnect always fails with this error in log:

```
2017-12-09 15:58:10 | 3e54 | Failed to open \.\Global{F8041029-39C6-456D-9C4B-565CB72F8167}.tap

2017-12-09 15:58:10 | 1e40 | Disconnected
```

It seems that openconnect want to use the same TAP device that already used by openvpn. so I installed more TAP devices by taking advice from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210071/how-to-create-a-2nd-tap-adapter-for-openvpn-client-on-win7/21210158 . But openconnect seems always to use the same TAP device of openvpn although there are some unused TAP devices there. Does anyone have some clues to solve this?

the version of openvpn is "Openvpn 2.3.11" and "Openvpn GUI v10"

the version of openconnect is "openconnect v7.08" and "openconnect GUI v1.5.1"

Comment: Did you try to tell OpenVPN to use a different TAB device? Also consider making the article you read a link. As it is, it's just text.

Comment: I have solved this problem by run Openconnect firstly,  then add a static route to the OpenVPN server as this: route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask  255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1 before connecting the OpenVPN. Because Openconnect will fail when encountering  an error of the first TAP device has been used by other process, while OpenVPN is more SMART to find  the next TAP device to connect, here is the log of Openvpn:

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by:

1. run Openconnect firstly, it will connect the server and establish a vpn connect to handle all the internet traffic.
2. add a static route to the OpenVPN server as this:

   route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask  255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
3. connect the OpenVPN.

I think above steps can solve the problem because Openconnect will fail when encountering  an error of the first TAP device has been used by other processes, while OpenVPN is more SMART to try the next TAP device to connect when first TAP device is not available, here is the log of Openvpn:

Sat Dec 09 19:14:07 2017 CreateFile failed on TAP device: \.\Global{F8041029-39C6-456D-9C4B-565CB72F8167}.tap

Sat Dec 09 19:14:07 2017 TAP-WIN32 device [以太网 4] opened: \.\Global{D9022776-41C4-413E-8611-703510DC3D98}.tap

Comment: which version of openconnect do u have?